# How can I specify key argument in sort() function however complex the argument be?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a nested list having elements of format `['name',float_val]`.

```
Nlist = [['naveen',31.5],['murali',44.1],['sai',23.1],['satya',23.1]]
```

I want to sort the above nested list by float object. 
How should I specify the 'key' argument in sort() function to fulfill my need?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
sort(x, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22416923)

Comment: @MichałZiober an answer being code-only [DOES NOT warrant deletion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/6296561). If you feel like it, downvote it, but deleting code-only is overkill in most cases (including this one).

Answer (score 0):

According the original [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/sorting.html):

> Both list.sort() and sorted() have a key parameter to specify a
>   function to be called on each list element prior to making
>   comparisons.

Note that you can use both `list.sort()` or `sorted()`:

> Python lists have a built-in list.sort() method that modifies the list
>   **in-place**. There is also a sorted() built-in function that builds a **new**
>   sorted list from an iterable.

You can find some useful examples [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/sort).

```
# take second element for sort
def takeSecond(elem):
    return elem[1]

# your list
Nlist = [['naveen',31.5],['murali',44.1],['sai',23.1],['satya',23.1]]

# sort list with key
Nlist.sort(key=takeSecond)

# print list
print('Sorted list:', Nlist)
```

**Out:**

```
Sorted list: [['sai', 23.1], ['satya', 23.1], ['naveen', 31.5], ['murali', 44.1]]
```